# Select first visible tab index

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-tabstrip

I have a personalized tab directive that set the active tab as the first element:

```
    jQuery($element).data(`kendoTabStrip`).select(0);
```

But now the directive receive a hidden property, when doesn't exist a set the ng-show=false

```
  Reflect.defineProperty($scope.tabs.tabs[name], `liElement`, {
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: angular.element(`<li ng-show="false">{{tabs.tabs[\'' + name + '\'].title}}</li>`),
  });
```

Making the first visible element possibly different than the first selected, I tried

```
const index = $( "li" ).index($("li:visible:first"));
jQuery($element).data(`kendoTabStrip`).select(index);
```

but the index always returns 0, how do I get the index based on ng-hide property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const index = $( "li" ).index($("li[ng-show='true']:first"));
```

ng-show or ng-hide does not change "visibility" attribute. It hides elements based on "display" attribute

Comment: That partially worked, but only if is the only one array of tabs in the page, mine is third in the hierarchy so it keeps pointing at the first tab of the DOM, do you know how do I point at each tab index instead at the first of the DOM? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even with const index = $("ul").find("li[ng-show='true']:first").index(); it still points at the the first li of the page

Comment: in place of this $("ul") try having current selected tab

Comment: and I would seriously suggest not using DOM manipulations and using jQuery like this with angular......have ng-class on the li elements and change that based on $index on ng-repeat of li element, then style the class in css